# Sortable menu with submenu jquery UI

Tags: html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, submenu

i write a sortable list :
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ebadgh/4cYFP/

But i have some problem and i can't solve my problem with search in websites

1. When Drag Submenus to Main menus Location, my Submenu's width must change to `100%`
2. When Drag a Main Menu, all Chiles of that menu must dragged and if dropped under another main menu it and all child of it must change to sub menu of that main menu.
3. When Main menu Dragged to Sub menus Place of a menu, that's must get `margin-left: 40px;`

thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?  I'm currently trying to recreate Wordpress nav management and need something like this too.